# Multiple choice menu program in C using the switch statement and scanf () function

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program with choice menu using the switch statement in C.  Here's my code:

```
main ()
{
    char option;
    int test;
    start:
    printf ("Enter: ");
    scanf ("%c", &option);
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    switch (option)
        {
            case '1': 
                printf ("Test 1 : ");
                scanf ("%d", &test);
                break;
            case '2':
                printf ("Test 2 : ");
                break;
        }
    if (option != 'q') goto start;
}
```

The program is intended to repeat until 'q' character is inputted from the keyboard. The problem is whenever I try to input '1' from the keyboard for the first time (which executed the case 1), the next time I input '1' or '2' the program will skip case 1 (or 2) and go directly to the next loop, however after the next loop it executed the case 1 (or 2) normally. Besides, the case 2 (which don't have the scanf () function) everthing work correctly. I have also tried to remove the scanf from the case 1 and after that case 1 executed normally. Here're some of the output:

```
Enter: 1
Test 1 : 5
Enter: 1
Enter: 1
Test 1 : 7
Enter: 2
Enter: 2
Test 2 :
Enter: 2
Test 2 :
```

Can anyone explain to me what's wrong with my code and tell me how to fix it?

Comment: 1. Check the return value of `scanf` 2. Always use braces for any loop or if statement. If the contents is empty put a comment in to tell the reader that this is deliberate. 3. `goto` - No need to use it and should be avoided

Comment: You skip the input to the next newline when reading the choices, but option one scans additional data, which leaves the newline after that still in the stream. I suggest to use a two-step approach of reading entire lines with `fgets` first and parsing these lines then throughout the program. This should avoid asynchronities - each time the user hits enter will then be clearly a separate input, something you can't guarantee with `scanf`.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf - read the *notes*.

Comment: BTW I highly recommend reading *by lines*. Just slam on the keyboard a you'll notice some horrible behaviour with your current approach.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `goto` use a loop -

```
while(option!='q'){
   printf ("Enter: ");
  if(scanf (" %c", &option)==1){       // leave a space before %c and check return of scanf
  //while (getchar() != '\n');
  switch (option)
    {
        case '1': 
            printf ("Test 1 : ");
            scanf ("%d", &test);
            break;
        case '2':
            printf ("Test 2 : ");
            break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf ("%d", &test)` under case1 is invoked when the current character in *stdin* is the first character of the next line (this happens after `while (getchar() != '\n')` is done. `scanf ("%d", &test)` 'eats' this character (that is probably expected to specify the next line option kind) and due to this fact the call to `scanf ("%c", &option)` happening in the next loop iteration no more can 'see' that character (it 'sees' the next one instead).

Comment: What? You're answer is highly unclear. And judging by "_`scanf ("%d", &test)` 'eats' this character_", your answer seems to be wrong. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Going through your code:

```
scanf ("%c", &option);
```

you type `1\n` (`\n` is the newline character generated on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>). The above `scanf` consumes `1`, leaving `\n` in the standard input stream(`stdin`). Next,

```
while (getchar() != '\n');
```

consumes the `\n` and breaks out of the loop (as the condition is false). Now,

```
scanf ("%d", &test);
```

you type `<number>\n` (`<number>` is the number you input). The above `scanf` consumes `<number>` leaving `\n` in the `stdin`. After the `goto` gets executed, execution returns back to

```
scanf ("%c", &option);
```

**This `scanf` sees the `\n` in the `stdin` left over by the previous call to `scanf`, and consumes it, and thus, does not wait for further input.** This is the problem.

---

Fixes for it include changing

1. This:

   ```
     scanf ("%d", &test);
   ```

   to

   ```
     scanf ("%d%*c", &test); /* `%*c` scans and discards a character */
   ```
2. This

   ```
     scanf ("%c", &option);
   ```

   to

   ```
     scanf (" %c", &option); /* The space discards all whitespace characters, if any, until the first non-whitespace character */
   ```
3. Using `fgets` to scan a line and `sscanf` to parse the data accordingly

etc.

Answer (score -2):

```
Please consider I only started 3 days ago.
very easy solution I came up with is this one:

#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

char i,a,b;
a='a';
b='b';
printf("choose a greeting: for welcome type a, for hello type b:");
scanf("%c" ,&i);

switch(i) {

    case 'b':

    printf("hello");

    break;

    case 'a':

    printf("welcome");

    break;



}

printf(" Mr. Bigotes");

return 0;

}
```